# Yii widget with two inputs. How to specify surrounding HTML for each input?

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii-events

it is quite simple to customize the view if the widget produces only one input field:

```
<div style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 17px;">Страна</div>
<div class="row">
<label> This is something: <? $this->widget(); ?></label>
</div>
```

Sure, we could specify $html_pre and $html_post for each input and manage like that:

```
function widget.run()
{
    echo $html_pre1;
    echo CHtml::activeTextField(...);
    echo $html_post1;
    echo $html_pre2;
    echo CHtml::activeTextField(...);
    echo $html_post2;
...
}
```

But is very bad looking. Is there another way?

Comment: In my opinion it should be just one widget that generates a single textfield, the you can create another widget (or in the view) and call it twice.

Comment: The fields are dependent (dropdown for country & jquery autocomplete combobox for city)

Comment: ah ok, i don't understand your question. If you don't want the repeated code, you can render both fields in a third method which prints html code, then inside the run method then you call it once.

Comment: but is it okay to pass the html code in widget( options ) ? anyway, you gave me an idea to `1.` pass callback `$render = function(){ echo .. };` in options, or `2.` pass a php code in options, such as `$render = "<b>{$header}<b/>"`, and then execute this code from run()

Comment: It doesn't look good to pass html code as options, maybe some flags or content information.